# Calling related posts to a custom post type, taxonomy & Tag id

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I'm trying to call the related posts of a custom post type by the category of the post that is loaded on the page.

Below is where I am at -

```
<?php                                               
    $blogcats = get_the_term_list();

    if (( 'post' == get_post_type() )) 
    {
        $posttypenews = 'post';
    }

    if (( 'blog' == get_post_type() )) 
    {
        $posttypenews = 'blog';
    }
?>
    <div id="news-related-posts-title" class="clear"><h1>Related Posts</h1></div>
      <?php
        $related = get_posts( array(    
            'numberposts' => 5,
            'blog_cats' => $blogcats,
            'post_type' => $posttypenews,
            'post__not_in' => array($post->ID)
        ) );
        if( $related ) foreach( $related as $post ) {
            setup_postdata($post);
      ?>

        <div id="news-related-posts">

            <div id="news-related-posts-container">

                <div id="news-related-posts-left">
                    <?php  the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail'); ?>
                </div>

                <div id="news-related-posts-right">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    <?php }
    wp_reset_postdata(); 
?>
```

If I change `$blogcats = get_the_terms();` to `$blogcats = 'the tag_id';` is works, but I'm struggling to call it from the post thats loaded...

Am I missing something obvious?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

[`get_the_term_list()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_term_list#Returns) returns HTML but you are trying to use it as if it returned a term ID -- `'blog_cats' => $blogcats,`. That is not going to work. You will need to use `get_the_terms()` and a `tax_query` (I think. I am not 100% sure).

Something like:

```
$blogcats = get_the_terms($post->ID,'category');
// var_dump($blogcats);

$blogcats = wp_list_pluck($blogcats,'term_id');
// var_dump($blogcats);

$related = get_posts( 
  array(    
    'post_per_page' => 5,
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
                'taxonomy' => 'category',
                'field'    => 'slug',
                'terms'    => $blogcats,
        )
    ),
    'post_type' => $posttypenews,
    'post__not_in' => array($post->ID) 
  ) 
);
```

Comment: Might wanna throw an `is_array` in there - `get_the_terms` can return `false`.